# reading xml file incorrectly, return value 0 when in file is 1

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm creating a xml file with the variable

verificacaoconjunta

This is a piece of the xml file

```
 // <tabelaGERAL>
 //   <Nome>Verificacao conjunta</Nome>
 //   <Valor>1</Valor>
 // <tabelaGERAL>
```

it states clearly that the value of it is 1

but when i read the table as in here:

```
        DataTable lertabela = new DataTable();
        lertabela.ReadXml(path);

        verificacaoconjunta = lertabela.Rows[4]["valor"].ToString();
```

it suprisisingly returns 0, i created a button to check for it's value on the table and here's the result

http://puu.sh/8tkmC.png

any hint on what might be wrong?

EDIT:
The full xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="tabelaGERAL" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="tabelaGERAL">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Nome" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Valor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <tabelaGERAL>
    <Nome>Accao G</Nome>
    <Valor>10</Valor>
  </tabelaGERAL>
  <tabelaGERAL>
    <Nome>Accao Q</Nome>
    <Valor>15</Valor>
  </tabelaGERAL>
  <tabelaGERAL>
    <Nome>Accao W</Nome>
    <Valor>7</Valor>
  </tabelaGERAL>
  <tabelaGERAL>
    <Nome>Tipo de verificacao</Nome>
    <Valor>1</Valor>
  </tabelaGERAL>
  <tabelaGERAL>
    <Nome>Verificacao conjunta</Nome>
    <Valor>1</Valor>
  </tabelaGERAL>
```

Comment: Post the complete XML. Perhaps you're looking at the wrong row?

Comment: It's not the wrong row, but i will post the whole xml file in edit

Comment: I genuinenly have no idea why it's reading the wrong value, i've double checked the path,  the way it reads the table, the file from where it reads the table, and ultimately the file has the "1" in there, is it perhaps because of the format string?

Comment: Your XML is invalid. You're missing a closing tag. However, after adding this in and running your example code I get the correct result: `1` in my console. Can you post the rest of your code in context? You mention a `format string`, what format string? I can't see one in your example

Comment: @DGibbs the code is enormous, so i fitted those elements which are accurate, i could send it over an email, because it has around 1500 lines of code.. I've set up the program to read the xml file early in the program and display a messagebox immediatly after with the value of verificacaoconjunta, it does display 0 on me. Actually, it reads correctly all values, except that one. I meant string, because it reads from a sort of text file. (I'm a beginner.)

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `verificacaoconjunta`. What does it read? Do you do anything with `verificacaoconjunta` after setting the value? It is definitely returning `1` for me.

Comment: @DGibbs I put the breakpoint when it tries to read the file, it shows a 0 there but, unexperienced as i'm i might be wrong, i took a screen shot with the result of the breakpoint, the value of verificacaoconjunta (as i believe it is), and the path and xml file right next to it, could you take a careful look? I don't quite know how to interpret break points http://puu.sh/8tm06.png

Comment: Have you set `"0"` as a default value for that string? Perhaps the string is being reset after it has been assigned the value from the file? In your screenshot you need to move to the next line as the variable has not been assigned the value yet.

Comment: @DGibbs it's showing 1 in the line after, correct! so something must be changing its value after? It's pretty strange because there's really nothing that's changing it's value, it's the same as the other variables

Comment: Yep, I'd guess that you have set a default value for that string of `"0"` somewhere and it's being reset to that after parsing the XML. Unfortunately, wouldn't be able to tell you how to fix it without seeing the whole code. Step through the code `F10` and keep going until you see the value get put back to `"0"`, that will be where the issue is.

Comment: Solved, i used the break points and went on to check what was changing the variable, and now i understand what it was, i'd hardly ever understand what it was without DGibbs hints. For anyone having a similiar issue just try the same, you will eventually find where the variable is changed.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. The debugger is a powerful tool!